# What is the proper way of connecting firebase with redux-sagas?

Tags: firebase, react-native, redux, redux-saga

I am building react-native app, where I use `react-native-firebase` and `redux-saga`. This is my first project using `redux-saga`, hence I am learning. So far I got the authentication of the user using the following:

```
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';

function* loginEmlPwdSaga(action) {
  try {
    const auth = firebase.auth();
    const data = yield call(
      [auth, auth.signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword],
      action.email,
      action.password,
    );
    yield put(loginSuccess(data));
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(loginFail(error));
  }
}
```

However, now I am stuck at the point, where I want to subscribe to the collection. In `react-native-firebase` I would use the following:

```
firebase.firestore().collection('users').onSnapshot(...)
```

I am not sure what is the best approach to handle subscribes in `redux-saga`. Can you show me the pattern that I can use for the future usage of onSnapshots (testable one)?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way to subscribe to a firestore collection using redux-saga is to use a channel:

```
function * syncUsers () {
  const ref = app.firestore().collection('users')
  const channel = eventChannel(emit => ref.onSnapshot(emit))

  try {
    while (true) {
      const data = yield take(channel)
      yield put(successAction(data))
    }
  } catch (err) {
    yield put(errorAction(err))
  }
}
```

This will dispatch an action (created by `successAction(data)`) every time the firebase pushes a change to your client.

You can also use a library like [redux-saga-firebase](https://github.com/n6g7/redux-saga-firebase) to automate this part and simply use:

```
function * syncUsers () {
  yield fork(rsf.firestore.syncCollection, 'users', {
    successActionCreator: successAction,
    failureActionCreator: errorAction
  })
}
```

> Disclaimer: I'm the author of [redux-saga-firebase](https://github.com/n6g7/redux-saga-firebase).

> **UPDATE:** redux-saga-firebase is no longer maintained and is not compatible with Firebase 8.

Comment: I have a large data and its stopping view until all the data is not set by reducer. Any solution to avoid this problem ?

Comment: @n6g7 How do you initialize redux-saga-firebase when you're using react-native-firebase?  I took a look at the redux-saga-firebase docs but I'm not initializing firebase in my JS code since its done in the native code.

Comment: @bzlight it looks like react-native-firebase exports a firebase instance (`import firebase from 'react-native-firebase';`, see https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/initial-setup#Example-Usage) so you can then create an rsf instance with something like `new ReduxSagaFirebase(firebase)`. I've never actually done this but it sounds liek it should work. Let me know!

Comment: Perfect, that's what I thought it was so I had already coded it!  I'm testing it today and I'll let you know how it goes

Comment: @bzlight have you had success with that solution? I am currently manually using the `react-native-firebase` like an API but using `yield call(firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc('userId').get)` results in a `cannot read property _customUrlOrRegion of undefined at nativeModuleKey` error

Comment: @n6g7 your suggestion worked perfectly!  I wrote it exactly as you suggested. 
 ```import firebase from "react-native-firebase";
const RSF = new ReduxSagaFirebase(firebase);```

I'm trying to listen to a document in firestore named with the current user's ID in react native but I'm having trouble passing in a variable to the to the channel.  Usually I do this by passing in the userId when a fetch function is called but since I'm listening, I'm not sure how do pass in the variable on startup.  Do you have any suggestions?  I'm working off your syncTodosSaga example in the Firestore section

Comment: @DheerajY Yes, n6g7's solution is working perfectly for me.  I would suggest using his redux-saga-firebase package, it's pretty easy to work with.  I posted my function to listen to firestore in the comment below, was too long for this comment.  You setup this saga in your index saga as a spawn().

Comment: @DheerajY  ```import firebase from "react-native-firebase"; const RSF = new ReduxSagaFirebase(firebase); 
export function* watchSquadChannel(userData) {
  try {
    yield put(syncSquadLoading());
    const channel = RSF.firestore.channel(
      "collectionName/documentName",
      "document"
    );
    while (true) {
      const response = yield take(channel);
      const {
        _data: {
          event: { data }
        }
      } = response;
      yield put(syncSquadSuccess(data));
    }
  } catch (error) {
    yield put(syncSquadFailure(error));
  }
}```

Comment: @bzlight It's difficult to help in the comments, would you mind opening a new question and posting some code examples? :)

Comment: @n6g7 good call!  I posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57338307/redux-saga-channel-pass-in-variable-for-api-call .  Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Ironically, I'm reading this post by @n6g7 because I need to replace his redux-saga-firebase package in my project because it's no longer maintained. :(